# Скрипт автоматически меняющий цвет текста

Tags: javascript, css

друзья.

Есть такой сайт
https://neon-show.ru/

[image: У меня есть аналогичный блок]

У меня есть аналогичный блок но не знаю как задать или найти решение.Прошу помочь с решением.

Comment: Нет конечно,я хочу такое реализовать но не знаю как,и не знаю как правильно это сформулировать то есть анимация или функция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не сразу понял вопроса, немного запутанно написали, такое решение вас устроит?:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let active = document.querySelector('.active')
  let first = document.querySelector('span')
  if(!active) {
    first.classList.add('active')
  } else {
    if(document.querySelector('.active + span')) {
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active')
      active.classList.remove('active')
    } else {
      active.classList.remove('active')
      first.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
}, 1e3)
```

```css
.active {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<span>Текст 1</span>
<span>Текст 2</span>
<span>Текст 3</span>
<span>Текст 4</span>
```

#### Вставьте этот код в сайт:

```js
let spans = [...document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-widget-wrap.elementor-element-populated > .elementor-element.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > span')],
  index = 0

setInterval(() => {
  let active, first = spans[0]
  spans.forEach((e, i) =>  {
    if(e.classList.contains('active')) {
      active = e
      index = i
    }
  })
  if(!active) {
    first.classList.add('active')
  } else {
    if(spans[index+1]) {
      spans[index+1].classList.add('active')
      active.classList.remove('active')
    } else {
      active.classList.remove('active')
      first.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
}, 1e3)
```

#### Не забудьте про стили!:

```css
.active {
  color: rgb(205, 0, 255);
}
```

Comment: То что нужно !!!Спасибо большое очень помогли.Но еще вопрос а класс active вещать как понимаю у родительского дива ?

Comment: @Joni, Не понял вопроса, что вы имеете в виду под "вещать"? Вы имеете в виду так: `.parent .active` или что? Если так как я сказал, то да, пожалуй лучше так, тогда можно будет применить `.active` и к другим элементам и сама анимация не испортится, если вы снова не использовали тот же селектор для родителя.

Comment: @Joni кстати, забыл упомянуть, если мой ответ решил вашу задачу, то, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку слева от моего ответа, вам не тяжело, а мне приятно :)

Comment: Я обязательно поставлю галочку,мне тоже приятно когда таким людям пишу коммент или ставлю галочку.

Comment: Если первому span присвоить класс active сразу, и использовать два toggle вместо add/remove, можно сократить решение. Также можно не делать запрос `'.active + span'`, а проверять значение `active.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: @Joni так ещё бы оно ошибку выдаёт, ожидалось что вы измените селекторы, чтобы подходило под ваш сайт, сейчас попробую посмотреть какие селекторы нужны.

Comment: Все сработало крутоо,спасибо еще раз огроменное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать CSS-анимацию:

```css
.hl {
  animation: switch 4s step-start infinite;
}

.hl:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 1s; }
.hl:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 2s; }
.hl:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 3s; }

@keyframes switch {
  25% { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<span class="hl">First</span>
<span class="hl">Second</span>
<span class="hl">Third</span>
<span class="hl">Fourth</span>
```

Свой вариант на JS также приведу:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.hl');
let curIdx = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  spans[curIdx].classList.toggle('active');
  curIdx = ++curIdx % spans.length;
  spans[curIdx].classList.toggle('active');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="hl active">First</span>
<span class="hl">Second</span>
<span class="hl">Third</span>
<span class="hl">Fourth</span>
```